# In pine, is it possible to just take a window of N candles to perform something?

Tags: pine-script

Specifically, let's suppose i want the moving average to be applied only for the last N candles( 5 for example) and plot it,is there a way to do it?

I'm a rookie with this code so need help!

Answer (score 0):

That's what the `length` parameter is for.

> ***length (series int)*** Number of bars (length).

Alternatively, you can do such calculations with a `for` loop.

Sma example:

```
pine_sma(x, y) =>
    sum = 0.0
    for i = 0 to y - 1
        sum := sum + x[i] / y
    sum
```

Comment: It doesn't allow to plot it from the candle i want to choose. Thiss should explain better: want to be able to anchor the moving average to a specific bar, so that the number of periods averaged is always the same as the number of bars elapsed since the anchor bar.